# What are Established Users?

Tags: support, users, privileges

Meta already has a page with same title as this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user, but it *doesn't* answer its own question.

So, to repeat, what is an "Established user"?

Secondary question (if permitted): Of course this is a peer-reviewed site, but is it possible, on Meta Stack Overflow, to get some adult supervision? My motivation is my seven-word naive question [Puzzled about the display of two up/down votes tallies at the same time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153249/147362), which got hammered.

Comment: Votes work differently on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences. Re secondary questions, it's not a good fit for the format... do keep in mind what Popular Demand said in your other question: `Meta SO users aren't immune to the "downvoting things because they seem too easy/simple/obvious to the downvoter" syndrome. I wouldn't worry about it too much... Meta rep isn't much use.` that said, yes, the replies you received were admittedly much less friendly than they could/should have been.

Comment: The privilege page sufficiently describe what an "established user" is, what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: On the privilege page look to the right. An established user is a user with 1000 reputation.

Comment: How about both sides chill a bit. Meta users - *try* to be nice. Joseph - relax, votes here really don't matter, and pay attention to the advice people are giving you, too.

Comment: As for "adult supervision", well the downvote arrow reads: "This question does not show any research effort". And your question didn't, as the answer to it is in the "established user" privilege page, a page you were notified to read when you gained the privilege (on Stack Overflow).

Comment: It says `"established user 11%"`, presumably from `1000`'?

Comment: On Meta you are not yet an established user. You are 11% on your way there.

Comment: I must admit that I am really puzzled and dismayed by the responses to this question for `support`. For now, have to take my children out for Hallowe'en for now, so I guess I give up.

Comment: If you ask what an "Established User" is while linking to a page which explicitly states what it is, people might find your question lacking in research effort. If anything, you might have wanted to clarify what exactly you did not understand or what was unclear to you in addition to the information already provided to you.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey: In the future, you might want to consider some empathy while writing the question. If you were *reading* a question which called for "adult supervision" because a poorly-researched question had been downvoted, how would you be likely to feel? Criticizing a group of people at the same time that you're asking them for help is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am extremely appreciative of your comment. And I apologise for the phrase "adult supervision". But that is exactly what I would like.  At the very least, perhaps someone could delete everything in this `"thread"`? But never-the-less, my simple original my seven-word question remains unanswered.

Comment: Related: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the **[privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user)** you've linked:

> Established users are those who have been participating on the site
>   for a fair amount of time. They gain the following privileges.
>
> - They may view the vote counts on posts

I think that sums it up pretty clearly, and there's further explanation for it too, on that same page.

The name "Established User" may sound a bit misleading. The fact is those are the only two privileges you get at 1000 reputation points.

---

As for your secondary question. When I got me a new privilege on Stack Overflow, I made sure to read the respective **[privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user)** very carefully, and then try the features explained there. That question you've linked shows no such research effort, even when you were given the information on a silver platter. As an "Established User", you should be fairly familiar with the site, the controls, and where to get information regarding different topics.

Also, don't feel bad. **[Voting on meta sites is often a measurement for agreement, not usefullness of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)**.

Answer (score 0):

"So, to repeat, what is an "Established user"?"

"Established User" is a privilege.

All privileges are things that can be earned given a certain number of earned points.

To see how many points it takes to earn a particular privilege, click on the "privileges" link, and look on the right hand side of the page. It will list each privilege by name. 
Click the one you want, and now on the right-hand side it will list the number of points required for that privilege.

In this case, "established user" requires 1000 points.

The page that you point to is the description of the "established user" privilege, and if you look on the right-hand side you can see the points-requirements.