# What is the point of the "Established User" privilege on meta SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges, vote-count, privileges-page

You can see the vote counts at only 100 reputation here. As far as I understand, [all it lets you do is see vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user). But here on meta it adds no new abilities, so all it is is a confusing privilege that is useless. Perhaps if you want to keep the whole "Nice job!" element it could be made into a badge. But this privilege on meta SE is useless at best and at worst confusing.

Comment: I also asked this 11 years ago, in a heavily down-voted question, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153276/147362.

Comment: Slightly related: *[What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There used to be more to it, i.e. the expandable user card but that was [given to everyone in 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334941/can-we-make-the-expanded-user-card-privilege-universal/342575#342575)

So now this exists in a vestigial form on this site because it's the base site for the network and apparently it's [not worth the development time to change this value to 100 in the help centre and elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379771/privilege-page-tracker-and-notifications-still-indicate-that-1-000-reputation).

Comment: Specifically, it's not currently possible to customize privilege help pages on a per-site basis (unlike other regular Help Center pages) – and it doesn't really make sense to change this privilege help page network-wide just to mention that it works differently on MSE.

Comment: But why is that the case? @V2Blast